# Visual Studio builds debug configuration, but not release configuration

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0, tfs, visual-studio-2013

This particular problem is a big one.

In my current configuration Visual Studio 2013 builds my project **if** it is in *Debug* configuration, but not **if** it is in *Release* configuration.

Somehow when I select *Release*, 160 errors pup up and when I go through them they are in impossible places. Here is one example.

Visual studios Error is the following:

> Error    3    ; expected    E:\Users\Robert\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GW2.NET\GW2.NET\GW2.NET\V1\MapInformation\DataProvider\ContinentData.cs    96    36    GW2.NET

And here is the code in question:

```
public static async Task<T> GetContentAsync<T>(string apiMethod, List<KeyValuePair<string, object>> arguments, Categories category)
    {
        var response = await GetJsonAsync(apiMethod, arguments, category);

        return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response));
    }
```

You see there isn't any error. If there were one, the Debug configuration wouldn't build either. I already tried to clean the solution and got the latest from TFS, and I deleted and recreated the configurations.

For now I am at my wit's end. How can I fix this?

The project is a C# 4.0 project with the Microsoft async, JSON.NET, and Rest# packages.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, if anyone else has the same problem, here is what I did. Thanks to [Dylan Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64644/dylan-smith), I got to the solution.

Open your .csproj file with a text editor of your choice. I used [Notepad++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notepad%2B%2B), but Visual Studio is also working. At the top there should be elements called *PropertyGroup*. Those elements define your build configurations. For me there were two:

One for *Debug*:

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
        <DocumentationFile>bin\Debug\GW2.NET.XML</DocumentationFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

And one for *Release*:

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
        <DebugType>none</DebugType>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
        <DocumentationFile>bin\Release\GW2.NET.XML</DocumentationFile>
        <LangVersion>4</LangVersion>
        <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

Apart from the obvious differences, with the first two nodes (*DebugSymbols* and *DebugType*), the main difference was the **LangVersion** element. I deleted it and voilà the project builds in release mode too.

So if you have the same problem as me, open the .csproj file and delete this node. This should solve it.

P.S.: What does the *LangVersion* element mean? If I change it from 4 to, say, 4.0, I get the following error:

> Invalid option '4.0' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default

Comment: LangVersion is the version of the C# language/syntax that the compiler will use.  The async and await features you are using in your code are C# 5+ only.  So having LangVersion set to 4 in the csproj will make the compiler fail.

Comment: Even if the async/await keywords come from the MS BCL package? Because that's what I use for those keywords, we target c# 4.0 because of backwards comparability.

Comment: async/await keywords are part of C# 5, not the BCL.  The Task Parallel library (which are the BCL types that are used to implement the async concepts) were part of .Net 4, but if you want to use the language syntactic "sugar" of the async/await keywords you need C# 5.  If you want to do async in C# 4 you have to use the Task types directly.

Answer (score 10):

If you are really stuck, one thing you could do is open up the .csproj file in a text or XML editor and inspect the actual XML content in there. You're trying to figure out what settings/properties are set differently based on Debug/Release configurations. This might give you some insight into what it is doing different between the two configurations.

Comment: I'm at this post because I had a Solution that would compile in Release but not  Debug. The problem was that a C++ component Project required C++17 and despite it being set to do so, in debug it just ignored C++17 features and showed them as errors. It turned out the Language specification was not present in its .vcxproj file under <ClCompile>.

Answer (score 1):

If you are building a [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX) setup project using Visual Studio 2010 with your own custom dialog boxes and your project builds in debug mode, but not in release mode, then go to menu *Project* → *Properties* → set *Tool Settings* to *Release Mode* and check the checkbox *Suppress ICE validation*.