# Can’t load .winmd references when building in Release Mode

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I need to add a NuGet package that depends on a reference `Windows.winmd`. I can build the project and run normally if building with Debug. However, the problem is when I switch to build in Release mode, it fails to build with the following error:

```bash
Error       Could not load file or assembly 
'file:///C:\Users\myrepo\packages\thepackage\lib\net47\Windows.winmd' or one of its dependencies. 
Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
```

My research told me it is the `.winmd` files that can cause such problem. These are all the possible solutions I can find on SO but none works:

1. [GenerateManifests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29826962/9107694): The security tab is not shown in the build option or the publish page. I don't think I'm enabling it.
2. My `Windows.winmd` file [is not blocked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45221477/9107694) or missing.
3. [Enable loadFromRemoteSources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34400546/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-operation-is-not-supported-exception-from-hres) does not help because the file is not over the network. (It's in `\packages`).
4. Switch the Release build to use the Debug configuration does work, but this conflicts the goal of building it in Release.
5. Change `Copy Local` to false in the Reference Properties page, and add a `Windows.winmd` [into my Framework SDK file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3101105/9107694). I've also tried to specify a different reference path for it, but the error still persists.
6. Compare and tweak the Debug and Release build setting page, as well as [comparing the .csproj file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908927/visual-studio-builds-debug-configuration-but-not-release-configuration) .

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>SecurityRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>false</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
    <LegacyPublishPropertiesPageEnabled>true</LegacyPublishPropertiesPageEnabled>
    <RegisterForComInterop>false</RegisterForComInterop>
    <PublishDatabases>true</PublishDatabases>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

.NET Version: .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can build it through by edit the csproj file and add `Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"` on the reference.

However, I'm not sure if missing this dependency will break the release someday in the future.

```
<Reference Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" Include="Windows, Version=255.255.255.255, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\thepackage\lib\net47\Windows.winmd</HintPath>
</Reference>
```