# Could not load Windows.winmd when Generate serialization assembly is On

Tags: .net, visual-studio, build, release

I have a NuGet package that depends on a reference file `Windows.winmd`. It works fine in Debug, but during the Release build, I encounter this error:

```bash
Error       Could not load file or assembly 
'file:///C:\Users\myrepo\packages\thepackage\lib\net47\Windows.winmd' or one of its dependencies. 
Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
```

I've confirmed that the Windows.winmd file isn't set to read-only or blocked. To move on, I've disabled it by adding `Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"` on the Windows.winmd reference in csproj.

I've noticed it is the config **Generate serialization assembly** being on that causes the issue. What is the actual problem and solution of this issue?

---

I'm using .NET framework 4.7.2

Comment: As a side note, I've pretty much tried all solutions showed on SO before deciding to disable it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77159764/can-t-load-winmd-references-when-building-in-release-mode

Comment: Note the `net47` in the path. That implies .Net 4.7, but you're still on 4.6. I recommend upgrading your .Net version, and while I was at it I'd probably go all the way to 4.8. This should be an _easy upgrade_ with no code changes: only install the new SDK and runtime, and update the target in the project properties in VS. But also look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41649597/referencing-library-using-windows-winmd

Comment: I've mistyped, I'm using 4.7.2. Thanks for pointing out! I'll try the update to 4.8 as well

Comment: For some reason turning off Generate Serialization assembly will fix the issue. I'm not sure why though...